# Webscraping with Python( Container tracking website)

Tags: python, html, excel, web-scraping

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiXCJ.png)

Hi Guys if you see the above picture

The complete portion starting from

```
<DIV> then <H4> and <table>   </DIV>

I have to extract First <H4> and
```

then all the table contents

i have already done this with VBA but i want to do it with Python 3.5

Any suggestion how can i think of extracting this data,

reason i am asking here because i have to print this into excel sheet ( every  tag into new line

Comment: please post the url,

Comment: Any effort? Anything? SO is not place for getting your job done instead of You, but rather helping You if You stuck somewhere in the process.

Comment: yes the effort is already done using VBA, i am facing problem with python login to website, so by the time i just wanted to know how i can proceed for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `BeautifulSoup` library

Here's the documentation:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/